# Persistent Connection in C socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

I have written a client code to create a socket and send a request to the client and as HTTP 1.1 uses Connection:Alive by default still the connection closes.How can i create a persistent connection such that the server listens to every request until the connection is closed.The client side code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

void error(char *msg){
perror(msg);
exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int sockfd, portno, n,i;
int Max_Requests;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *server;

char buffer[256];
if (argc < 3) {
   fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
   exit(0);
}
Max_Requests=atoi(argv[3]);
portno = atoi(argv[2]);
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (sockfd < 0)
    error("ERROR opening socket");

server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
if (server == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
}

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    error("ERROR connecting");

i=0;
while(i<Max_Requests){
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0)
        error("ERROR writing to socket");

    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0)
        error("ERROR reading from socket");

    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    i++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: To begin with, at what index is the *first* argument in the `argv` array? Consider that `argv[0]` is the command name, and the first argument follows directly...

Comment: 1) It's `Connection: Keep-Alive` and 2) the server is not required to honor that. You just state that you are able to support keep-alive connections, should it decide it wants to use one.

Comment: And what are you *sending* to the server? Please show us the request, *verbatim*.

Comment: argv[0] is the command's name argv[1] is the server's IP argv[2] is the port at whch server is running and argv[3] is the no. of requests that the client want to send during the persistent connection.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your use of `fgets` to read input from the user to form the request.

The problem with it is how you use it, namely to read *a single line* that you send to the server as the request. You then promptly go to the `read` call and wait for the response, without having sent the full request and its headers.

That will lead the server to time-out and close the connection, since it haven't received a full request.

Comment: Is he supposed to add some sort of sleep() in between? Is it the latency issue that he sends and goes to read too fast or is it that you need to explicitly add headers for full request?

Comment: @Anton9988 The OP needs to send a proper HTTP request, with headers and body. Not only a single line of user input (which could be anything). The server will not reply unless a proper HTTP request have been sent.